# pull image from other GitLab repo's container registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 2 private Gitlab repositories. One (Repo A) has Container Registry and I want to use it from another repository (Repo B).

```
Repo B's .gitlab-ci.yml

image: "registry.gitlab.com/x/y"
```

Is it possible to do this? I have no idea on where to put the user/password configuration. Note that i am able to access the Container Registry by running docker login/pull command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this?

Yes.

> I have no idea on where to put the user/password configuration.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry

Comment: it worked after adding $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG. thanks.